# Why is our new clan member ineligible for war?

Tags: clash-of-clans

A member just joined our clan, but is ineligible for war.

She was not previously in a war, and her profile doesn't have the ineligible symbol and time like it would for others, but it still says she can't opt in for war.

Is this a bug or is there an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

If a member is inelligible for war, it means they left their previous clan while a war was in progress.

From the SuperCell post:

> Members who are new to your clan will be ineligible for war if they left their previous clan while a war was in progress. They will become eligible for war again when the previous war is completed. You can check your clan member list to see if any members are ineligible for war, and see when they will be eligible again. If you start the clan war while members are still ineligible, those members will not be able to participate.

Comment: Thank God for this rule. People who jump after being added to a war need to be in a penalty box.